# How do I get swipe to delete a row in a specific section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I have two arrays. Each Array gets a section. When the user swipes the row and selects delete it must delete the appropriate row in the right section. How do I change my code to get it to delete in the right section.
 This is my code so far.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If you're data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
        if (self.numberOfSections == 1)
        {
            [self.playerNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            //code here needs to determine which section needs to be deleted
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (self.numberOfSections == 1)
```

to:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It did help. I was looking for the if (indexPath.section == 1) though I must keep if (self.numberOfSections == 1) because that determines if there is one section or more than one section.

Comment: @user1898829 you're welcome. An accept would be nice too. And I wouldn't know that you want to keep `(self.numberOfSections == 1)` without seeing the full code(or a better question structure).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code snippet:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
          NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
          [tableDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:row];      
          [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Also refer this [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Comment: Please Look at my solution below and see if it can be improved and integrated with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If you're data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
        if (self.numberOfSections == 1)
        {

            [self.playerNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
             if (indexPath.section == 0)
             {
                 [self.team1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             }
            else
            {
                [self.team2 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```